# How to switch keyboard layouts for different languages?

Tags: keymap, input-method

**Q:** how do I switch between input methods for different languages when using a non-standard keyboard layout?

I have to edit text in two different languages.  I would like to be able to use my keybindings across the two languages, except, of course, when inserting text into the buffer.  It looks like I should be able to [`toggle-input-method`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html#Select-Input-Method) (`C-\`) and select the alternate language.

So far, *almost* so good.

Here's the rub: I use the English Dvorak layout, which I set at the OS level (ie, with [`setxkbmap`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml)).  When I `toggle-input-method`, the text I insert would be correct if I had a QWERTY layout (the standard in the US), but comes out as gibberish because I'm on Dvorak.  (FWIW, when I switch my layout to standard US, it works fine.)

So: *how do I inform Emacs that I'm using Dvorak* so that `toggle-input-method` and friends translate my keypresses to the correct characters in the other language?

Comment: swedish-postfix and other compositional input methods work for me, which methods are you having trouble with?

Comment: @shapr: I'm switching between English and Arabic.  The problem seems to be that I'm using a Dvorak layout at the OS level, as the toggling works fine when I use the standard US layout at the OS level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a method to change the physical layout definition for input method by setting `quail-keyboard-layout-type`. But it looks Dvorak is not among the possible candidates in `quail-keyboard-layout-alist` in my Emacs 24.4.

You can either define a new physical keyboard layout by looking at definition of `quail-keyboard-layout-alist` in `quail.el` or create a new input method by defining corresponding Arabic keys for Dvorak layout.

I'm not experienced in the first, but I can testify the second approach is easier than you think. (I had to create an Ottoman Turkish input method on top of Farsi.) Copy `arabic.el` (which resides in my Debian system at `/usr/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/leim/quail/arabic.el.gz`) to your home `site-lisp` and change the keys per your preferences. Also, don't forget to change the input method names etc. You just created a new Dvorak-Arabic input method.

I can update the answer with more details if anything seems complex.

Comment: Thank you!  That set me on the correct path.  I'll post an additional answer that lays out how I got there on the `...-alist` version.

Comment: You're welcome. You may think to submit your update to the `quail-. *-alist` to Emacs development. I'm sure there are other Dvorak users that will benefit from it.

Answer (score 7):

@EmreSahin put me on the right path to answer this question, so I'm laying out a little bit of the detail in case anyone else ever has to deal with a problem like this themselves.

As Emre points out, we need to add a Dvorak layout to `quail-keyboard-layout-alist`.  It turns out that the `quail` library is not well-documented in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html#Select-Input-Method), in which two related functions are mentioned in passing on one node.

However, after consulting [this help thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help/92887) and, especially, the [EmacsWiki page on Russian with Dvorak](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WritingRussianWithDvorak) (from which this answer cribs), I've think I've got it figured out.

The docstring for the variable `quail-keyboard-layout` describes what we need to put in `quail-keyboard-layout-alist`.  It's a long string corresponding to 6 rows of 15 keys each.  Each row corresponds to the unshifted and shifted values of each key, for a total of 30 characters per row.  I'm less sure about the following point, but it appears that, for what I'll call "semi-standard" keyboards with 4 rows of keys, the first and sixth rows should each be 30 blank spaces.

The big reveal:

```
(require 'quail)

(add-to-list 'quail-keyboard-layout-alist
             `("dvorak" . ,(concat "                              "
                                   "  1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)[{]}`~  "
                                   "  '\",<.>pPyYfFgGcCrRlL/?=+    "
                                   "  aAoOeEuUiIdDhHtTnNsS-_\\|    "
                                   "  ;:qQjJkKxXbBmMwWvVzZ        "
                                   "                              ")))

(quail-set-keyboard-layout "dvorak")
```